# redirect to user User details

Tags: json, authentication

I'm new here and I need help.
I need to build a system of students who log in through a JSON file.
After connecting, the user is redirected to his personal page with all his details. When the user is redirected, a blank page is loaded, and I can't figure out how i pause the running script until the page loaded complete. I would appreciate it if you could help me.
this is my js code:

```js
ocument.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (evt) = >{
  evt.preventDefault();
  let usernameContent = document.querySelector('#input-login').value;
  let pwContent = document.querySelector('#input-pw').value;
  tryusername(usernameContent, pwContent);
})

function tryusername(username, password) {
  let usernameFound = false;

  fetch('db.json').then(response = >response.json()).then(data = >{
    data.forEach(element = >{

      if (username === element.username) {
        usernameFound = true;

        if (password === element.password) {
          //alert('access granted');

          //console.log(data);
          clearInputs();

          var res = Object.entries(element);
          console.log(res);
          for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            window.open("/test.html");
            let FirstName = res[0];
            let LastName = res[1];
            let ID = res[2];
            let Mobile = res[3];
            let Email = res[4];
            let Uname = res[5];
            let Type = res[7];
            let department = res[8];
            let Year = res[9];

            document.getElementById("User").innerHTML = Uname;
            document.getElementById("FirstNamee").innerHTML = FirstName;
            document.getElementById("Email").innerHTML = Email;
            document.getElementById("LastName").innerHTML = LastName;
            document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = ID;
            document.getElementById("Mobile").innerHTML = Mobile;
            document.getElementById("Type").innerHTML = Type;
            document.getElementById("department").innerHTML = department;
            document.getElementById("Year").innerHTML = Year;
          }
        }

        else {
          alert('password incorrect. access denied');
          clearInputs();

        }
      }
    });
    if (!usernameFound) {
      alert('login not registered');

    }
  })
}

function clearInputs() {
  document.querySelector('#input-login').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#input-pw').value = '';
}
```

```html
</head>
<body >
    
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <label for="login">
            <p>Login:</p>
            <input id="input-login" type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Insert your login" required>
        </label>
        <label for="pw">
            <p>Password:</p>
            <input id="input-pw" type="password" name="password" id="pw" placeholder="Insert your password" required>
        </label>
        <input id="button-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="fetch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```